# Patrón Factory en Python 3 con MySql

Tags: mysql, python, mvc

Vengo de programar en PHP y allí utilizaba para acceder a los datos de MySql el patrón Factory, estoy intentado utilizarlo en Python, y posteriormente usar los datos para Flask. Es correcto esta manera en la que escrito o existen otras formas mejores de acceder a los datos, la idea es construir datatables de Jquery en una plantilla HTML.

```html
import pymysql.cursors
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Product:
    def __init__(self, idproducte,referencia,nom,preu,iva,ean13,categoria,subcategoria,imatge):
        self.idproducte = idproducte
        self.referencia = referencia
        self.nom = nom
        self.preu = preu
        self.iva = iva
        self.ean13 = ean13
        self.categoria = categoria
        self.subcategoria = subcategoria
        self.imatge = imatge

class productFactory:
    @abstractmethod
    def productos(connection):
        listProducts = list()
        with connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = "SELECT id,referencia,nom,preu,iva,ean13,categoria,subcategoria,imatge FROM productes_general.productes"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                for row in cursor:
                    pr = Product(row['id'],row['referencia'],row['nom'],row['preu'],row['iva'],row['ean13'],row['categoria'],row['subcategoria'], row['imatge'])
                    listProducts.append(pr)
        return listProducts
        

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='**',database='productes_general',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cataleg = productFactory.productos(connection)

for ct in cataleg:
    print(ct.referencia, "->", ct.nom)
```

Con esto, con productFactory.productos() puedo generar un JSON para pasar los datos a la plantilla.
¿Es correcta la forma de proceder?

Comment: Cuando dices "Patrón Factory" te refieres al Factory Method Pattern de la GoF?

Comment: Si, utilizaba algo como esto, https://phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te refieres al [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) de la *Gang of four*, definitivamente no lo estás implementando correctamente.

El objetivo de este patrón de diseño es el de poder usar una interfaz común para la creación de objetos sin el compromiso de que nuestro código cliente tenga que saber la clase que está instanciando. La principal ventaja de esto es el *decoupling* que se consigue entre nuestra lógica de negocios y las demás clases del sistema.

Más allá de eso, estás haciendo uso del módulo `abc` de manera incorrecta. En primer lugar, si quieres implementar una clase abstracta, esta debe heredar de `abc.ABC`. En segundo lugar, el objetivo del decorador `@abstractmethod` es el de, bueno, crear métodos abstractos. ¿Cuál es la función de un método abstracto? Pues el de darle una definición concreta en las clases que deriven de la clase de abstracta. En tu caso ni siquiera estás especializando la clase (que creo que querías que fuese abstracta) que tienes en `ProductFactory`.

Hemos de recordar que en Python no son necesarias las clases abstractas, métodos abstractos ni interfaces explícitas. Si bien es cierto que yo soy un fanático de ellas para obligar ciertas buenas prácticas, su uso en Python viene dado de una manera no nativa y opcional.

Ahora bien, ¿cómo se implementaría de manera más sensata este patrón de diseño? La primera condición que tendríamos que tener, es que tengamos varios modelos (clases que representen tablas de la base de datos) a los cuales tenga sentido delegar sus instanciaciones a las clases factories. Si no tienes esta condición, entonces la implementación de un patrón de diseño es desaconsejada porque aumenta la complejidad en tu base de código.

Además, siendo los Patrones de Diseño unos amigos muy cercanos a la Programación Orientada a Objetos, es menester mantener los principios fundamentales de este paradigma de programación. Por lo tanto deberíamos respetar el [SRP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) y tener una clase que se encargue de hacer la conexión con la base de datos, y aparte de eso, tener las clases responsables de darle forma a nuestro patrón de diseño.

Entonces, considerando lo anterior, pudiésemos implementar algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
import pymysql.cursors
from collections import namedtuple


DB_INFO = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '**',
    'database': 'foobarbaz'
}

Person = namedtuple(
    typename='Person',
    field_names=[
        'id',
        'name',
    ]
)

Product = namedtuple(
    typename='Product',
    field_names=[
        'idproducte',
        'referencia',
        'nom',
        'preu',
        'iva',
        'ean13',
        'categoria',
        'subcategoria',
        'imatge'
    ]
)


class DBManager:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
        **DB_INFO
    )

    def fetch_all(self, table, fields):
        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = f'SELECT {fields} FROM {table}'
            cursor.execute(sql)
            return cursor.fetchall()


class Factory:
    db_manager = None
    table_name = None
    model = None

    def fetch_all(self):
        fields = ','.join(self.model._fields)
        rows = self.db_manager.fetch_all(self.table_name, fields)
        return [self.instantiate(data) for data in rows]

    def instantiate(self, data):
        return self.model(**data)


class ProductFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db_manager = DBManager()
        self.model = Product
        self.table_name = 'productes_general.productes'


class PersonFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db_manager = DBManager()
        self.model = Person
        self.table_name = 'some_persons_table_name'


# Código cliente que aproveche las factories
def print_records():
    for factory in PersonFactory(), ProductFactory():
        print(factory.fetch_all())
```

Repasando un poco lo que sucede acá:

- Estoy añadiendo un modelo adicional llamado `Person` para que tenga un poco más de sentido el implementar el patrón de diseño.
- Como no hay ninguna lógica implicada (hasta ahora) en los modelos, podemos (*y deberíamos*) usar una `namedtuple` para representarlos. Esto con el fin de evitar tener [modelos anémicos](https://maximilianocontieri.com/code-smell-01-anemic-models). Además, tienes el plus de tener objetos inmutables.
- `DBManager` es la clase encargada de servir como puente entre Python y los comandos sql.
- La clase padre `Factory` contiene la lógica necesaria para llevar a cabo la operación de recuperar los registros, y es lo suficientemente flexible como para integrar otras operaciones similares. Incluye un método `instantiate()` que puede ser sobreescrito por factories concretas, en caso de ser necesario realizar alguna operación adicional al momento de instanciar una clase.
- Las clases derivadas `PersonFactory` y `ProductFactory` subreescriben el método inicializador `__init__()` para inyectar las dependencias necesarias. Es decir, el modelo y el nombre de la tabla.
- Observa cómo en tu código cliente se están creando (e imprimiendo) objetos usando una interfaz agnóstica de las clases que se están instanciando.

Si bien es cierto que las clases factories derivadas parecen innecesarias porque solo contienen la sobreescritura de `__init__()`, el objetivo del ejemplo es mostrar la flexibilidad y el bajísimo *coupling* que se consigue con esto.

Como puedes ver, todo tu código de allí en adelante puede continuar existiendo con tan solo una única referencia a las clases (namedtuples, hasta ahora) `Product` y `Person`. Esto es, en esencia, el objetivo de implementar los patrones de diseño.

**Adicionales**

- Puedes serializar fácilmente cualquier instancia de tus modelos a un formato JSON con el módulo `json`. (`json.dumps`)
- Recordar que en Flask se utiliza el ORM [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), por lo cual te aconsejo que si deseas trabajar con ese framework, orientes tu aprendizaje hacia allá, en lugar de crear tú mismo tus estructuras de código para comunicarte con una base de datos relacional.

.
.
.

*nota: Disculpa lo extenso de la respuesta. Es sábado, hay cuarentena aún y tengo tiempo libre :D*